# Multiple Cursors in TeXShop

Tags: texshop, keyboard, shortcut

Is there any way to get multiple cursors in TeXShop? This can make doing repetitive edits much easier. I am referring to a way to get more than one cursor in the text, with every key pressed applying to both cursors. In Jupyter and Sublime Text this is achieved by doing `command + click`. Is there an equivalent thing in TeXShop or a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

The MacOS does not support multiple cursors automatically:

- [How do I get multiple cursors throughout OSX?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/174618/how-do-i-get-multiple-cursors-throughout-osx)
- [Two mice, two pointers, one mac](https://superuser.com/q/649325/107780)

Since TeXShop uses the standard OS input methods, there is no two-cursor support in the program.